# Move a button 50% of the left side css

Tags: html, css

Why this wouldn't work?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" style="left: 50%">Enter <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: The button needs to be positioned relative, absolute or fixed. Anything except the default 'static'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't include a detailed overview of your CSS, but `left`, `top`, `bottom` and `right` are only going to work for *positioned elements*. This means elements that have their **position** set to either `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed` or `sticky`.

Read more about this at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left